# CMD - Finding the password of admin account using another admin account in windows 7

Tags: windows, security, cmd

I have two admin accounts, one of which i forgot the password. I have another admin account but i don't want to reset the password but reveal or see the old password using CMD. I have been searching for this since a long time but had no luck with it! Hoping I would get the answer this time :)

I know to reset password using CMD prompt: net user < user > < password >

But my old emails have the same password as this account. So i want to Retreive my old password rather than reseting it!

Comment: I think it would be a rather enormous security flaw for an admin to see anyone else's password.  Including another admin.  I think resetting it is your best option.  Besides...  Once you do that, you can always SET IT to whatever you want.  Including what you THINK the old password was.

Comment: You simply cannot do this; if you could it would be a major security flaw. You can't retrieve the password of any other user (you can't even retrieve your own in plain text in most cases). Think about it from a logical standpoint: I'm Ken, and I'm an admin on this machine. You're Evenure, another admin on this machine. I want to find out your password so I can get into your account and email and other stuff. Should that be allowed? You're going to need to just deal with not having it and exercise more care in the future so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: I am certain passwords are not stored in plain text on Windows and are instead hashed. So the password has to be reset to regain access.

Comment: The "imagine if this were possible" thought experiment is helpful here. [When people ask for security holes as features: Stealing passwords](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/04/414602.aspx).